# Where should I put `favicon.ico` so bokeh serve can find and render it?

Tags: bokeh

I have a [directory format](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format) app, named `myapp` like:

```
myapp/
   |
   + -- main.py
   + -- favicon.ico
   + -- static
           |
           + -- some.img
```

If I run `bokeh serve myapp`, I keeps getting `404 GET /favicon.ico (::1)`.

Where should I put `favicon.ico`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create folder "templates" and add "index.html" with

```
{% extends base %}

{% block preamble %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="myapp/static/favicon.ico">
{% endblock %}
```

And move your "favicon.ico" in the folder "static".
So you have:

```
myapp/
   |
   + -- main.py
   + -- templates
           |
           + -- index.html
   + -- static
           |
           + -- favicon.ico
```

Here are some more information about extending the bokeh template.
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#standard-template

Also kudos to the answer from bigreddot and the helpful comment by gepcel.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an HTML template to a Bokeh application, under the `templates` directory. With that, you can specify an favicon location in the normal way in the `<head>` of your template. For an example of an app that uses a template, see [the crossfilter demo](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/crossfilter) in the GitHub repo.

The template just needs to have

```
{{ plot_div }}
{{ plot_script }}
```

in the `<body>`. The app is rendered wherever the `plot_div` is located.

Comment: Thank you. This is simple and works fine. Just in case somebody else need this. `favicon.ico` should be put in `static` directory, and `index.html` should have this line `<head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="mypython/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`. Put it under `myapp` directly won't work.

Comment: Is this still the recommended way of adding a favicon in bokeh 1.4.0? It's not working for me, the content of my `templates/index.html` is `{% extends base %}
<head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="app-name/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"></link></head>`. Is it still working for you @gepcel?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there's no easy way to serve `favicon.ico` with `bokeh serve`. If you really need `favicon.ico`, the most straightforward way to do it, in my opinion, would be to switch from `bokeh serve` to a Tornado application, just as in [the example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.11/examples/howto/server_embed/tornado_embed.py). It's much more flexible and doesn't require that much configuration.

Comment: By embeding it with tornado, it will get the whole benifit and flexibility. May be I will try it later. For now I just want do some simple demonstration, and templates works simple. Thank you.